# Difference Between NSOutlineView and NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

Tell me the difference between NSOutlineView and view based NSTableview as I know view based table view may not contain tree controller and NSOutlineView can have tree controller object

is it true or wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/Articles/AboutOutlineViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000107-BBCBJFFG) it best:

> NSOutlineView is a subclass of NSTableView that lets the user expand
>   or collapse rows that contain hierarchical data. As in a table view,
>   an outline view displays data for a set of related items, with rows
>   representing individual items and columns representing the attributes
>   of those items. Unlike a table view, items in an outline view are not
>   in a flat list, but rather may be organized in a hierarchy, like files
>   and folders on a hard drive, or managers and employees in an
>   organization.

So, yes, what you say is true.

Comment: But NSOutlineView is subclass of NSScrollView

Comment: @SnehalTanawade No it's not: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsoutlineview_Class/Reference/Reference.html